# Regular expression is working in standalone but not in web applicaiton

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a regular expression which is working fine if I run as a standalone java application and returning true:

```
public class Example {

    private static final String VALID_ADVISOR_NAME_FORMAT = 
            "[a-zA-Z" + " " + "-" + "'" + "&" + "(" + ")" + "]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isInvalidAdvisorName("%%%%%"));
    }

    public static boolean isInvalidAdvisorName(String name) {
        return !name.matches(VALID_ADVISOR_NAME_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

But if I use the same method in my web application (runs in Tomcat), the output is `false`. Can anyone tell me why `"%%%"` is getting considered as invalid in standalone app but valid in web app that runs in tomcat?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `+` (or `*`) at the end of your pattern? <del>And `%%%%%` won't match 'cause there's no `%` in your pattern.</del> (And why are you concatenating literal strings like that?)

Comment: @Biffen It makes sense if you apply multiline formatting for clarity. Many regex gurus recommend that. OP may just have compressed it for SO.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik As a self-proclaimed regex guru I say it makes it hard to read in this case; it's all just a single class.

Comment: @Biffen The *expected* behavior is not to match `%%%%`. All the negatives make that tough to see, too.

Comment: `" " +   "-" + "'"` will simply represent `" -'"` regex which means *range of characters* between space and `'`. I doubt that is what you wanted.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oh, got me there.

Comment: Good point by @Pshemo---and one more reason not to mess with concatenation of the pattern. There's ample opportunity to mislead.

Comment: @Biffen .The problem is even though  "%" is not there in the pattern, that's getting matched in tomcat server  and saying that "%%%%" is a valid one.

Comment: @Ramson Yeah, I get that now, the multiple negatives got me.

Comment: @Ramson The first thing I must doubt is your conviction that `%%%%` is the actual input string you are testing. By what *exact* technique have you obtained that proof?

Comment: Assuming that your Tomcat is using same JVM as standalone application only way for results of method to be different is when you will pass different argument. Double check what argument you are passing to your method.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik
Actually, valid characters are **lower case characters, upper case characters,space,-,', &**
But in my web app, % is getting accepted as a valid one. Can you please tell me what is the correction should I do to the regex apart from * at the end. Thanks.

Comment: @Ramson `[A-Za-z '&-]*`, or replace `*` with `+` to not match empty strings. Note that `-` should go at the end so as not to create a range of characters. (Why did you have `()` in there?).

Comment: Do you acknowledge that you are actually asking two things at once: the original question (not related to the regex), and how to fix your regex to conform to your actual requirements? Whatever changes you make to the regex, the standalone behavior will be exactly the same as the behavior within the deployed application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` represents range of characters in [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/). So just like `a-z` represents all characters which are between `a` and `z`, regex like `[ -']` (you are creating it via `" " + "-" + "'"`) represents all characters between `space` and `'`.

Now lets take a look at indexes of some characters in [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/):

- index of space is `32`
- index of `'` is 39
- and index of `%` is `37`

so `%` is placed between `space` and `'` so it is accepted by regex `[ -']` as valid character.

To make `-` literal inside `[  ]` you need to either

- escape it with `\-` (written as string `"\\-"`)
- or place it somewhere where it can't be treated as range indicator like:

  - at start of character class `[-foo]`
  - at end of character class `[bar-]`
  - after already created range `[a-z-1]` where `a-z` will represent range and `-` placed right after them (and `1`) will be treated as literals.

So you can try with this pattern (and drop the concatenation part, it actually makes your regex harder to read and spot mistakes).

```
VALID_ADVISOR_NAME_FORMAT =  "[a-zA-Z \\-'&()]";
```

Also if you want your pattern to accept more than one characters in described range add `+` after character class (`+` represents *one or more* quantified).

```
VALID_ADVISOR_NAME_FORMAT =  "[a-zA-Z \\-'&()]+";
```

Comment: Thanks so much to all. Could any body please suggest a site where I can learn regex betterly.

Comment: @Ramson For me (and for many others) http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is best source for information about regex in general. If you want to learn about regex in Java official tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ is quite good. Also  documentation of Pattern class contains many important informations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html